# Unable to change character_set_server on MySQL

Tags: mysql, character-set

I have converted my database to UTF8 but the character_set_server is still Latin1.

Is it compulsory to change it to UTF8 or can I just leave it like that?

This is a production server, so it's not possible to reboot the MySQL database.

[image]